# Serial Device in Android/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, zebra-printers

I am ignorant in this field. I have a tablet attached to a thermal printer I think the printer is connected to a `/dev/tty` port. I need to use that printer. Is it possible to develop a WEB APP in Android by using `Cordova`, or it is better to developer a native Android APP ?

Answer (score 0):

With the availability of cordova printer plugins like [printer-plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer) and [zebra-printer-plugin](https://github.com/mmilidoni/zbtprinter), developing mobile app using cordova framework should be much simpler and faster compared to the native approach provided it meets all your business needs.

Comment: Uhm.. but I need to enumerate devices attached to the OS. In my case, the printer is internal (think of a POS)...

Comment: @giuseppe if its gonna be a lot of device interactive operations then its better to proceed with native approach from performance stand point. But as i mentioned earlier it all depends on the business needs